# Cannot use result from Database as key into hash of hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash, dbi

I'm having a strange issue when trying to create a Hash of Hash in perl. If I try to use a result from fetchrow_hashref as a key in a Hash of Hash it fails with a "Not a hash reference" error. If I use it in a Hash its fine.

```
            my %resulthash;
            my $sql =qq{ SELECT *  FROM product };
            my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute(); 
            while ( my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) {

              #the line below works fine                
              $resulthash{"RANDDOM"}{'address'} = "test address";

              #this also works  
              $resulthash{"$res->{'username'}"} = "test address";                

              #the line below fails with "Not a HASH reference"
              $resulthash{"$res->{'username'}"}{'address'} = "test address";

            }
```

Could somebody please explain why? and how I can use the result from my DB as a key into a hash of a hash?

Thank you.

Comment: By "fine" do you mean you checked what was in the hash? Because there is a pretty good chance that hash insert hasn't done what you think.

Comment: Please, add the output of `print Dumper($res, \%resultHash);`

Answer (score 0):

Quotes around keys should be omitted when the keys are identifiers, so try:

```
$resulthash{$res->{'username'}}{'address'} = "test address";
```

Otherwise, you can do it like this:

```
$resulthash("$res->{'username'}"} = {address => "test address"};
```

Comment: Might be worth clarifying that what the quotes are doing is making a string that probably isn't the desired result.